# Different spacing around \circ in different places in the same document using the exact same commands

Tags: spacing

```
Why is this happening? Compare the two outputs, both using $f \circ g$.
```

[image]

This produces the first output:
such that $f \circ g =  \txtn{id}_Y$ and $g \circ f = \txtn{id}_X$,

and this produces the second output:
and both $h \circ f$ and $g \circ k$ are continuous

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Perhaps, in the second line, (La)TeX is trying to make a very tight line fit, exactly, in a single line: in such cases, the spacing around binary operators is allowed to shrink to zero points.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show us small complete document which will reproduce your problem. i can't reproduce your problem. however,

Comment: @GuM If that's what it is indeed doing, then how do I fix this?

Comment: Well, this cannot be considered an error: (La)TeX is simply doing the job it is supposed to carry out, that is, to typeset a given text in the best way possible, given the circumstances.  The only viable remedy in such cases, if you really find the output awful, is to rewrite the passage so to allow a more visually pleasant sequence of line breaks.